# Fix scroll lagging when records are more than 30

Tags: reactjs

I’m building an app that displays 30 hotel records component that scrolls through a complex list of components 60,90,120 records, I have used auto-scroll onClick button display more details

If I scroll in small increments everything runs smoothly, but when I try to do a faster scroll, the scrolling becomes jittery and I start getting the [Violation] messages in the console:

[Violation] 'message' handler took 326ms

searchResults.map((data, i) => {
return (

)
})

Comment: please add more code to clearly state the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a good approach might be implementing [virtual scrolling](https://medium.com/@alvinnguyen116/virtual-and-infinite-scrolling-in-react-d56a05976cd2) to just render the elements that are currently scrolled into your view